# Add tag for [namespaces]?

Tags: discussion

There seem to be plenty of questions related to namespaces. Would it be helpful to add a [namespaces](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/namespaces) tag?

https://drupal.stackexchange.com/search?q=namespaces

Comment: Wouldn't object to this.  Namespaces come up in contexts outside of PHP directly related to Drupal concepts: module names, plugin IDs, etc.  We need to identify some good questions that would be improved (findability wise) by adding this tag.

Comment: @mpdonadio Here is maybe an [example](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/60830/88044). At the moment, it's only tagged [tag:7]. I think it would be helpful for some of the questions in the search list to have a tag related to their specific question, rather than just the Drupal version.

Comment: _Namespaces_ is a too vague concept. In fact, between the questions listed from that search link, two are about XML namespaces, another one isn't even about namespaces (since they cannot be called), a fourth one is not about namespaces. Even considering just PHP namespaces, that is not a Drupal-only concept.

Comment: I'm inclined to agree with @kiamlaluno that `namespaces` might be a bit too broad (given that that term crops up in various different technologies). I'd be happy with `php-namespaces` or something, though, because they're intrinsic to D8 IMO

Comment: Here's a good example: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/124976/understanding-drupal-8-and-namespaces

Comment: I am fine with @Clive suggestion, as long as questions using [tag:php-namespaces] just because are PHP questions or questions about other namespace types are edited to remove the tag.

Comment: The tag usage guidelines can be written to clarify the intended use.

Comment: The tag guidelines don't prevent users from using the tag when it's not appropriate. Other users need to actively remove the tag when not appropriate.